# Dart xml find element from attribute value

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

Given the xml below, what is the most efficient way to access a `line` element with a specific `id` attribute value, e.g. `line id="2"`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document id="doc1">
  <line id="1">
    <data id="D1" value="20" />
eating
    <data id="D2" value="40" />
  </line>
  <line id="2">
    <data id="D1" value="90" />
drinking
    <data id="D2" value="340" />
  </line>
</document>
```

This is what I have at the moment. I don't know if there is a better way:

```
var lines = document.findAllElements('line');
    for (var line in lines) {
      if (line.getAttribute("id") == "2") {
        print(line);
      }
    }
```

Comment: That would be a simple XPath query.  Search pub for XPath and see if any of the packages are useful to you.  I'd start with https://pub.dev/packages/xpath_selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Slightly simpler would be to [filter](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables#example-using-where) with [Iterable.where](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html):

```dart
var lines = document.findAllElements('line')
    .where((line) => line.getAttribute('id') == '2')
    .toList();
```

At the end (optionally), I am converting the `Iterable` to a `List`, to make sure the document is only traversed and filtered once.

Answer (score 0):

you can use xml2json package for converting.
I made an example for you on the link that below

[Example Code Link](https://github.com/VeyselSahn/stflow_answers/blob/main/xml_elements/xml_elements/bin/xml_line.dart)

Comment: Thanks for taking to time to do that. In this case, I was looking to keep the coding to pure XML.